# load one-off page fast

Tags: theming

I want to create a landing page for my Google Ads on my site so that potential customers will be able to download and see the page very quickly. My site can be a bit heavy with CCS and javascript and other stuff sometimes.

All I want is to avoid losing potential clients due to a slow website. So I wonder if there's a simple way of the landing page being a light version of my site (with links to the "real" drupal site).

Many thanks

Oli

Comment: What's the main source of many CSS/JS - your theme or contrib modules? Would having that page as a plain static HTML work?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your website to load fast, you need to cache.

Go to Performance (/admin/config/development/performance)

and enable caching and aggregate css and javascript

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with No Sssweat. You also can use [Google Page speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) to guide you.

Some other comment problem is images. You can use [this link](https://tinypng.com/) to help you solve the problem as well.